# extract string that starts with T in vector of characters R

Tags: r, string

Hi I am trying to extract all the strings that start with T in this vector:

```
test <- c("bye | S-A-TX-1-1", "bye | b-c-TY-2-1",  "bye | d-e-TZ-3-3")
```

Therefore, I need to extract: "TX-1-1", "TY-2-1", "TY-2-1"

I tried using `test<- grep("^\\T[A-Za-z]", test)` but it did not work,
I saw similar posts but none with a specific pattern like this,
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is *no* string that starts with `T` (let alone `T*`) in your example. What is the expected output for your `test` input?

Comment: I need to extract TX-1-1, TY-2-1, TZ-3-3 I will edit the question, thanks

Comment: @i.b in this case you can just do `gsub(".+(T.+)", "\\1", test)`. But more generally what are the rules? Do you always want from the first `"T"` to the end of the string? Can there be more than one "`T`"? Can you have a string like `"bye | S-A-TX-TV-4"`, "bye | TT-2-1", or `"GTA | S-A-TX-1-1"`?

Comment: Thanks for your help! in the case of the string you gave as an example, I will always need the string that starts with first T so ```"bye | S-A-TX-TV-4"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test <- c("bye | S-A-TX-1-1", "bye | b-c-TY-2-1", "bye | d-e-TZ-3-3")

test_extract<- str_extract(test, "T[A-Z-0-9]+")

test_extract
#This pattern  "T[A-Z-0-9]+"  helps in matching either characters with letters in upper case from A - Z, digits from 0 - 9 or hyphen
```